# How to create a Event with a co-organizers in google calendar using node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to create an event in node.js using google.calendar('v3') with co-organizers?

I've been reading all the google documentation but I haven't found anything...

tks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Google calendar API doesn't have the ability to create an event with multiple [organizers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/events-calendars#organizers).

> Events have a single organizer which is the calendar containing the
> main copy of the event. Events can also have multiple attendees.

### Suggestion:

If the goal of creating multiple organizers in an event is to give others an ability to edit the event, you can [create a team calendar](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/sharing) and grant all members of your team the right to add and modify events in the calendar.

### References:

[Google Calendar API overview](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/overview)

[Sample Code for Creating Events in node.js](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#examples)

[Sharing & Attendees](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/sharing)

[Calendar Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/events-calendars#events)

Comment: The real problem is that when you create an event with a conversation through Meet and put guests who don't have the gmail. needs the organizer to approve the guest entry, this rule really doesn't make sense as the guest with another email like .hotmail, .outlook, .yahoo cannot access the meeting.

I did not find a solution, I will be forced to use another service to hold a video conference, absurd because my platform uses the google agenda service.