# How to make a script to create events in Calendar and add an account as a co-organizer using AppScript in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I already have a script that creates the event and adds guests, but I need one of these guests to be a co-organizer of the meeting.

I sought the information myself through this site https://aryanirani123.medium.com/create-calendar-events-in-google-calendar-using-the-calendar-api-and-google-apps-script-6dbc46146d21

I couldn't think of anything to add to the code, but I expect the script to follow this order:

1. Create the event
2. Invites the person highlighted in the spreadsheet column and makes them a co-organizer
3. Invites the rest of the accounts

Comment: `but I need one of these guests to be a co-organizer of the meeting.` From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/events-calendars#organizers) "Events have a single organizer which is the calendar containing the main copy of the event." Refer [How to create a Event with a co-organizers in google calendar using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75807667/1330560) for a suggested 
 (non-node.js) workaround.